# Find declaration for not linked CSS files in PhpStorm

Tags: html, css, phpstorm

In my project I've linked just **one minified css** file which I've **excluded from search** and **marked it as plain text**. That css file is generated automatically and **contains all other css files** in **folder marked as Resources root**.

But **PhpStorm** seems to be using for **finding declaration** just **files that are linked in html**. Is there any "hack" how can I force it to **see all files from selected folder**?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unfortunately PhpStorm only uses classes from explicitly linked css files when collecting the list of styles defined for your page.

As a workaround I can only suggest adding temporary links to source .css files, and remove these links in production version... or mark your generated minified css as CSS :(

Please feel free to file a feature request for css mapping support similar to the one used for JavaScript (creating a map of all symbols and, if element can't be resolved from explicit reference, just resolve it by name) to our [Issue Tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB). Related ticket: [WEB-11431](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11431).